# Offline Page during Azure Deployment

Tags: azure

I'm using Azure services for hosting a web app, and as I get closer to actually launching this thing, a thought occurred. When deploying, it can take upwards of 15 minutes before everything is up and running. During this time, the domain Azure is hosting is unavailable.

It would be pretty cool if I could throw up an interim page, similar to IIS's App_Offline.htm option. Is there an equivalent to this for Azure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way to work with a new version of your site is to leave the old version running in the Production slot until the new version is ready for service in the Staging slot.  Then you click the VIP Swap button and Azure quickly swaps the old version to staging and the new version to production.  There is no down time.

Comment: Or, use an in-place upgrade. Only one update domain will go down at a time, and so there's also no downtime. The only thing that will create downtime is if you delete the existing deployment, or if you only have one instance and do an in-place upgrade.